# rosrun can't open my video (ROS OpenCV)

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-melodic, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm trying to stream some video file (.mp4).
I wrote a node:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap("chaplin.mp4"); 

    
    cv::namedWindow("A_good_name", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    
    if(!cap.isOpened() )
    {
        std::cout << "\nCannot open the video file.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); //get the fps
        
    int waitKeyValue = 10;
    
    while(true)
    {
        cv::Mat frame;
        
        
        if(!cap.read(frame) )
        {
            std::cout <<"\n Cannot read the video file.\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        
        cv::imshow("A_good_name", frame);
        
        int key = cv::waitKey(waitKeyValue);
        
        if(key != -1)
            std::cout << key << std::endl;
        
        if(key == 32) //space button for pause
        {
            if(waitKeyValue)
                waitKeyValue = 0;
            else
                waitKeyValue = 10;
        }
        
        if(key == 27) //escape button for exit
            break;
    }
    
    cap.release();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.2)
project(task)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  message_generation
  cv_bridge 
  image_transport
  sensor_msgs
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)

###################################

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
find_package(SDL REQUIRED)
set(LIBS ${SDL_LIBRARY})

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS
  LIBRARIES task
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp 
                 rospy 
                 std_msgs
                 cv_bridge
                 image_transport

  DEPENDS system_lib ${LIBS}
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${SDL_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

##################################### build

add_executable(playVideo_node nodes/CVexample/PlayVideo_node.cpp )
target_link_libraries(playVideo_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} )
add_dependencies(playVideo_node task_gencpp)

#####################################

install(TARGETS 
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

I moved video (chaplin.mp4) in my code directory, but when I enter

> $ rosrun task playVideo_node

I get:

> init done
> opengl support available

> Cannot open the video file.

Then I tried to move video in execute file directory, but problem is same.
Does anyone has suggestion what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333427/rosrun-can%27t-open-my-video--(ros--opencv)/) by [Jovan](https://answers.ros.org/users/45853/jovan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosrun executes with the cwd in your current directory so relatively links should be relative to your current path. Not the source or executable directory.

For others reference roslaunch uses ROS_HOME
[Related roslaunch question](https://answers.ros.org/question/57075/how-to-save-file-to-the-current-directory-with-roslaunch/) Reference [roslaunch XML node attributes](https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jovan](https://answers.ros.org/users/45853/jovan/) on 2019-09-20**:
I understood, thanks.